# Is it possible to apply default filter on a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named Users(for example), and it has 3 columns(Id, Name, and IsDeleted), IsDeleted indicates the user is deleted, or not?

When i run below select statement(select * from users), is it possible to filter out the records which has IsDeleted equals 1, automatically? I have a database which designed as soft delete only, so there are many table with this IsDeleted column. when query database, we have to add where clause to filter these records out, it's very annoying, especially when query/join multiple tables. I want ask here, is there some feature(like default filter?) to do this. so,the deleted records can only be queried, when the table default filter is disabled.

Comment: You could, for example, create views for these tables

Comment: Create views for each table. I would never use such a design because your database cannot use it referential integrity anymore which will in time lead to currupt data

Answer (score 5):

A clean and easily understandable way to achieve this is with views. You could create a view that filters out users by this flag and returns all columns.

```
CREATE VIEW v_Users AS
    SELECT * FROM Users WHERE IsDeleted = 0
```

Then in all your queries you can use this view instead of the table.

```
SELECT u.email, u.name, likes.*
FROM v_Users AS u
INNER JOIN likes ON likes.user_id = u.id
```

Full example fiddle: http://rextester.com/QDN58706

Comment: @GuidoG Typo. Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

**Variant 1:** You can create new table with deleted records, trigger on deletion (or instead of insert/update/delete) and with delete move all records into new table. You don't have to remap your actual queries. You can have still foreign keys and you can force referencial integrity.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.r_users (s__row_id int not null identity(1,1), s__dml_dt datetime not null, s__dml_type char(1) not null, col1...)

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_del_users
ON dbo.users
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.r_users select getdate(), 'd', * from dbo.users

DELETE FROM dbo.users WHERE IsDeleted = 1
```

**Variant 2:** You can create view on filtered table/TVF/CTE.

There is not feathure you want, only scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply row level security which will add filter to the table.